# expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token { (C++)

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, token, curly-brackets

So I'm getting this error when i compile my code (expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token      {) I know there may be many of these errors out there on stackoverflow, but can't seem to find a solution:

I'm new to c++. Here is the code: I have to read data from a text file (data.txt) and display it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

FILE *fptr;
char country[5][20];
int population[5];
int landMass[5];
int option;
int i;
int countryOption;
int gdp[5];
int populationDensity[5];
int gdpHead[5];

//open file for reading
fptr = fopen("data.txt", "r");      

//Error checking
if (fptr == NULL) {                
   printf("Unable to open data.txt");
   return(1);
}

//input from user
printf("Hi welome to the country database!");
getchar();
system("cls");
printf("Select a country for information:\n");
printf("1)Canada\n");
printf("2)Italy\n");
printf("3)China\n");
printf("4)USA\n");
printf("5)Russia\n");
printf("6)All\n");
printf("Type in the option you want:");
scanf("%d", &option);
system("cls");

//reads data from data.txt and assigns to variables
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    fscanf(fptr, "%s %d %d %d", country[i], &population[i], &landMass[i], &gdp[i]);
    populationDensity[i] = (population[i]/landMass[i]);
    gdpHead[i] = ((gdp[i]*1000000)/population[i]); 

    if (option == 6) {
        printf("Here is info on all the countries in our database:\n");
        printf("Country: %s\n", country[i]);     
        printf("Population: %d\n", population[i]);
        printf("LandMass: %d\n", landMass[i]);
        printf("GDP: %d\n", gdp[i]);
        printf("Population density: %d\n", populationDensity[i]);
        printf("Population density: %d\n\n\n", gdpHead[i]);  
    }
}       

void countrySelection(int countryOption)
{
     printf("Here is some info on the country you chose:\n");
     printf("Country: %s\n", country[countryOption]);     
     printf("Population: %d\n", population[countryOption]);
     printf("LandMass: %d\n", landMass[countryOption]);
     printf("GDP: %d\n", gdp[countryOption]);
     printf("Population density: %d\n", populationDensity[countryOption]);
     printf("Population density: %d\n\n", gdpHead[countryOption]);  
}

//function that prints the info
if (option < 6) {
   countrySelection(option);
}                   

fclose(fptr);
system("pause");
return(0);

}
```

The data.txt looks like this:

```
Canada
42000000
9984670
1821000 
Italy
60920000
301230
2013000
China
1351000000
9706961
8227000   
USA
313900000
9826675
15680000
Russia
143000000
17098246
2015000
```

Any one have a clue as to what the problem is???

Comment: Cut down your code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: The closing parenthesis for main() appears to be missing.

Comment: Im also getting this error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Comment: See above, you're missing a parenthesis.

Comment: its right at the end or maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: void countrySelection(int countryOption) is nested inside main().

Comment: is that a problem... sorry I don't really know>>? and what should i do to fix?

Comment: woops, i can't put a function into another function?? right?

Comment: There is another big problem in the program, you are defining arrays with a size of 5 and in your loading loop you are going from 1 to 5 but the array indices (in C(++)) are going from 0 (to 4 in your case). So you are overriding other values in the last iteration of the loop. You have to change your loop to iterate from "i = 1; i <= 5;" to "i = 0; i < 5;".

Comment: could i just change the array size to 6?

Comment: Yes you could, but it would be waste of space becaues the first (index 0) element of the array is never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `void countrySelection(int countryOption)` inside the main function, which is not allowed in c++.

Move the function above the main function and it should compile.
Also you have to define the variables used in `countrySelection` as global variables, otherwise the function has no access to them.

Comment: i defined them as global, but whenever I run the program and call the function by selecting one of the option...(canada, usa, russia) i dont get any output

Comment: Your loading loop has the wrong iteration, change it to "int i = 0; i < 5; i++". See my comment on the question for more information.